# Determination of fluorescence lifetime by using oscillator strength?

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, electronic-structure, spectroscopy

$$k_r=2.88\times10^{-9}n^2\langle\tilde{v}\rangle_\text{av}^2 \int\varepsilon_{\tilde{v}}d\tilde{v}$$

$$f=4.32\times10^{-9}\int\varepsilon_{\tilde{v}}d\tilde{v}$$

I plan to use the above equations to calculate the lifetime $k_r$ of a fluorescent molecule. I need to calculate the oscillator strength $f$ in the 2nd equation, but I don't understand how to use the equation used to calculate the oscillator strength.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!! However I've editing your question by removing the screenshot, see here: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411/5. I've also removed your second question, see here: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5

Comment: That depends on what data you have. In quantum chemistry calculations, for example, you calculate f from the transition dipoles, not from the equation that you mentioned. Your equation is only useful when you want to calculate f from the experimental absorption spectrum. Moreover, please note that $k_r$ is not the lifetime; its reciprocal is the lifetime, but only when the non-radiative relaxation pathways of the molecule are negligible, which is frequently not true.